# telerik editor with iframe

Tags: telerik, telerik-editor

I'm using Telerik Editor, with following,

```
<div class="Telerik-Editor">
            @{
       Html.Telerik().EditorFor(model => model.Description).Name("Editor").FileBrowser(settings => settings
           .Browse("Browse", "ImageBrowser")
           ).Render();
        }
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
```

doing only above, it is working, (Editor is working) , but If I add iframe , then Editor is disabled.
Anybody getting this error/bug?

```
        <iframe src="mysomeurl" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I replied in the [Telerik forum thread](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/telerik-editor-not-working-with-iframe-on-document.aspx) which you opened you need to close the iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
```

Otherwise the browser expects the closing iframe tag and stops parsing the page any further.